# Are "father" and "farther" pronounced exactly the same in British English?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, vowels

In American English, "farther" is differentiated from "father" by the middle R, but I am talking about the British English in which the R's are only pronounced before vowels because so many "British English" varieties do pronounce the R.

I checked the pronunciations of the word "father" and "farther" in some dictionaries and they suggest that they are pronounced the same.

Cambridge Dictionary gives **/ˈfɑː.ðə/** for both ["father"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/father) and ["farther"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/farther) in British English pronunciation. Also I can't differentiate between both of them when I listen to Cambridge pronunciations.

Do British people pronounce them exactly the same?

Comment: I pronounce them identically.

Comment: They're identical for me too, but I might pronounce 'father' with a short vowel at times. The long vowel in 'fa**r**ther' results from the deletion of the underlying R. (You don't need to write the superscript r.)

Comment: Phonemically they are identical. Phonetically I wouldn't be surprised if *farther* turns out to have a slightly longer vowel if you looked at hundreds of real-life examples (as you can do with a corpus), since it's the less frequent meaning of the homophone..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My father is farther than my mother.

The consensus in the comment is that they are pronounced the same, or at least there is no phonemic difference.

> Phonemically they are identical. Phonetically I wouldn't be surprised if farther turns out to have a slightly longer vowel if you looked at hundreds of real-life examples (as you can do with a corpus), since it's the less frequent meaning of the homophone.. – legatrix

Note that in British English you can use "further" for the "more distant" meaning instead of "farther"  (AmE tends to use farther for physical distance and further for non-physical, as in "further from the truth")